# What could be the reason, every time my web part loads in workbench it stops on same line in the xx-web-part.js

Tags: spfx

While debugging in VS code in /_layouts/15/workbench.aspx, when the web part loads, the file localhost:4321/{name of web part}-web-part.js is shown and the execution breaks on line: `if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag)`

in function:

```
/******/    // define __esModule on exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.r = function(exports) {
/******/        **if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag)** {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/        }
/******/        Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/    };
```

F5 continues OK